# framework for SEO oriented web site

Tags: wordpress, joomla, content-management-system, opencms

I have to create a web site for a design company. Client's requirements are

1. Site must be fast loading
2. Site must be optimized for SEO - planning for a paid SEO process after site launch
3. Must integrate with facebook and other social networking sites.

The client will take care of the rest SEO processes. Now I just need to made a SEO friendly fast loading website.

I am new to this SEO process and bit confused about the framework to choose for the work.

Can anyone please suggest me a best and efficient framework in PHP for the process ?

From a lots of googling I found that Wordpress and Joomla! suits me.

But Joomla! is little bit heavy am I ?

These site contents a simple slide show and some articles and videos and protfolio and a contact form thats all

Any advises?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am an SEO expert and I find that Wordpress, even without plugins is very SEO friendly and not as complex as Joomla.

One SEO plugin I highly recommend is Yoast SEO http://yoast.com/wordpress/seo/

Another on is WP super cache to speed up the site http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-super-cache/

Hope this helps ;)

Answer (score 2):

Well, for fast loading you just need to be careful on which plugins to use, some load very slowly and have poor code.

You also can use a cache plugin, that will store DB queries on HD and use them later instead of remaking the same query on every pageload.

In the theme, use a clean one, that makes less WP calls. If pageload speed is realy a requirement, remove less needed information, like tag list (in this case u'll lose a bit of SEO value too) and some widgets.

The most important thing in SEO is avoiding external links that will take you juice out. I have a email and url obfuscation plugin, but I couldn't find it right now in wordpress plugins page.

Then use good permalink structure, choose wisely post slugs, build a proper page title, etc.